# Имя класса подключенной библиотеки совпадает с именем стандартной функции Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, классы

Подключаю следующий заголовочный файл:

```
template <class value_t>
class property
{
    /* ... */
}
```

И вызываю создание класса следующим образом:

```
property<double> *pd = new property<double>();
```

Ожидаю, что `property` будет ссылаться на класс как раз из подключенного заголовочного файла. Однако получаю ошибку, т.к. property ссылается на функцию из `qobject.h` (строка 399):

```
QVariant property(const char *name) const;
```

Можно ли вообще каким-либо образом (кроме переименования класса) сделать так, чтобы все работало?

Comment: то что вы назвали "подключаю заголовочный файл" никакого отношения ни к подключению ни к заголовочным файлам не имеет. Ну а так вопрос решен уже давно, смотрите `namespaces`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имена не совпадают, к объектам из глобального простарнства имен следует обращаться так:

```
::property<double> *pd = new ::property<double>();
```

А в `qobject.h` объявлен метод `::QObject::property`

Еще замечу, что для С++ библиотек недопустимо объявлять идентификаторы в глобальном пространстве имен. Поэтому стоит обратится к вендору библиотеки и указать на дефект.

Answer (score 0):

Для шаблонного класса, имя которого совпадает с функцией в текущем пространстве имён так или иначе переименование потребуется. А вот если бы класс `property` не был шаблонным, достаточно было бы написать так:

```
class property *pd = new class property();
```

Добавление `class` явно указывает компилятору, что дело идёт с классом, а не функцией.

В случае же шаблонного класса (если переименование не вариант) придётся разносить сущности по разным пространствам имён `namespace` и использовать полностью квалифицированное имя. Пример:

```
namespace myns {
    template <class value_t>
    class property
    {
        /* ... */
    };
}

myns::property<double> *pd = new myns::property<double>();
```